# How to truncate ^FD text in ZPL

Tags: c#, zebra-printers, zpl

My ZPL code:

```
^XA
^FO15,300^A0,25^FD Invoice #^FS
^FO150,300^A0,25^FD Date^FS
^FO300,300^A0,25^FD Cust #^FS
^FO400,300^A0,25^FD Name^FS
^FO650,300^A0,25^FD Amount^FS
^FO10,330^GB800,3,3^FS
^FO15,350^A0,25^TBN,305,25^FD200001^FS
^FO150,350^A0,25^FD10/26/2021^FS
^FO300,350^A0,25^FD100^FS
^FO400,350^A0,25^FDThis is a test customerrrrrrrrrr^FS
^FO650,350^A0,25^FD$129.90^FS
^XZ
```

The issue is that when a customer's name is too long it overlaps the the amount column. If the name is longer than the width of the column I would like for it to be truncated.

Comment: No. I tried this but it still overlaps

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to clip text with ZPL is to draw a white box after the text where it may overrun.  This is not a general purpose solution but it can be made to work for most cases.  From your example:

```
^XA
^FO15,300^A0,25^FD Invoice #^FS
^FO150,300^A0,25^FD Date^FS
^FO300,300^A0,25^FD Cust #^FS
^FO400,300^A0,25^FD Name^FS
^FO650,300^A0,25^FD Amount^FS
^FO10,330^GB800,3,3^FS
^FO15,350^A0,25^TBN,305,25^FD200001^FS
^FO150,350^A0,25^FD10/26/2021^FS
^FO300,350^A0,25^FD100^FS
^FO400,350^A0,25^FDThis is a test customerrrrrrrrrr^FS
^FX Draw a white box where the text may over-run ^FS
^FO645,345^GB150,30,30,W^FS
^FO650,350^A0,25^FD$129.90^FS
^XZ
```

Comment: Are you saying `^TB` does not work?

Comment: @GSerg:  Yes, `^TB` only clips on wrapped lines, after word wrapping.  For example, if you used the example text `^FDThis is a test customerrrrrrrrrr^FS`, you will see it wrap after the `test` and clip the remaining text.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post this as an answer although @GSerg link in the comments should solve the issue. This is the relevant ZPL code:

```
^XA
^FO15,300^A0,25^FD Invoice #^FS
^FO150,300^A0,25^FD Date^FS
^FO300,300^A0,25^FD Cust #^FS
^FO400,300^A0,25^FD Name^FS
^FO650,300^A0,25^FD Amount^FS
^FO10,330^GB800,3,3^FS
^FO15,350^A0,25^TBN,305,25^FD200001^FS
^FO150,350^A0,25^FD10/26/2021^FS
^FO300,350^A0,25^FD100^FS

^FO400,350
^A0N,25,25
^TBN,220,100^FDVeryLongCustomerNameGoesHereAndWillBeTruncated^FS

^FO650,350^A0,25^FD$129.90^FS
^XZ
```

Note that the TB command only works  for printers with firmware version V60.14.x, V50.14.x, or later, so if yours is older, this may indeed not work. This is the result in the simulator:

[image]

To wrap the text, simply set a smaller height for the text block as follows:

```
^FO400,350
^A0N,25,25
^TBN,220,30^FDVeryLongCustomerNameGoesHereAndWillBeTruncated^FS
```

Result:

[image]

As per comments, this will wrap if there is a space in the name. To always clip at the exact same location no matter the text, see @Mark Warren's answer. Another option is to do this in whatever code is creating the label ensuring the name is max N characters.

Comment: The OP doesn't want the text to wrap.  He wants it to be clipped

Comment: @MarkWarren He does not want the text to *overlap*. Not sure where it should be truncated. Edited the answer and clarified. Your answer is a nice trick by the way.